# Tweepy filter doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, filter, tweepy

I try obtain user's tweets by user id via filter method, but I have no results. I saw the same questions on forums, but it doesn't help me. Can someone help me resolve this problem?

my code:

```
from tweepy import StreamListener
from tweepy import Stream
import tweepy

access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        # process stream data here
        print(data)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener = StdOutListener()
    twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener)
    twitterStream.filter(follow=['1680410522'])
```

Comment: Can you check if 1680410522 is valid user id_str and NOT the tweet id_str? I had similar issue. your code looks OK. may be, you figured it out by now. :)

Answer (score 0):

twitterStream.filter(track=['UserName']) worked for me.